# Working correctly with static functions in many files from a C Extension for Python

Tags: python, c

I'm working with an C extension for Python and by the documentation I know that I must use `static` functions. The files are organized by this way:

`file1.c`

```
#include "file1.h"

static int foo1(int a)
{
    //Do someting with a
    return a;
}
```

`file1.h`

```
static int foo1(int a);
```

`file2.c`

```
static int foo2(int b)
{
    //Do someting with b
    return b;
}
```

`file2.h`

```
static int foo2(int b);
```

`extension.c`

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

static PyObject*
func(...)
{
    int a, b, x, y;

    ...

    x = foo1(a);
    y = foo2(b);

    ...
}

static PyMethodDef methods[] =
{
    {"func", func, METH_VARARGS, "Test function"},
    ...
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

//Remaining Python C structures and functions
```

I'm using `setup.py` with `setup` and `Extension` functions from `setuptools` module. When I run `python setup.py build`, obviously I receive an error message because the functions `foo1` and `foo2` are `static` functions and the file `extension.c` can't access them (actually, I'm using the extension without the `static` keyword in the functions `foo1` and `foo2`).

How should I proceed with the `static` keywords in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, 'static' functions are not visible outside the file they are defined in.

Therefore, suggest:

do not use the 'static' modifier on the functions.